# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments - Swift

Tags: swift

I pull data from the database, I have assigned variables to Array in the webservice because the data I have captured is more than one. On the Swift side, I want to assign the data I have captured to Array, since there is more than one data. But I have a problem like in the topic. The data I pull from the database is string. How can I assign the data I have captured to Array?

```
Error Line: // let article1 = detayTaxSonItem(aciklama: self.formAcıklamaSON, baslik: self.formAdıSoyadıSon, fiyat: self.formFiyatSON, adet:self.formADETSON,tarih:self.formTARIHSON)

struct detayTaxItemSON {
    let aciklama: Array = [""]
    let baslik: Array = [""]
    let fiyat: Array = [""]
    let adet: Array = [""]
    let tarih: Array = [""]
}

class TaxTableViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    var itemsSon = [detayTaxSonItem]()

  @objc func mustBILGICEKSON(){
                self.itemsSon = []
                        ...
                              do {

                                 if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                            for review in baslik {
                               if let soru_baslik = review["ADRES"] as? String {
                                    let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                                       DispatchQueue.main.async { self.formAcıklama.append(s)
self.collectionView2.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0)) } } }  }


                                 if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                   for review in baslik {
                       if let soru_baslik = review["ADI_SOYADI"] as? String {
                            let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                                                                          DispatchQueue.main.async { self.formAdıSoyadı.append(s)
self.collectionView2.reloadData() } }  } }


           DispatchQueue.main.async {

               let article1 = detayTaxSonItem(aciklama: self.formAcıklamaSON, baslik: self.formAdıSoyadıSon, fiyat: self.formFiyatSON, adet:self.formADETSON,tarih:self.formTARIHSON)

                                   self.itemsSon = [article1]
                                     } } catch let parseError {
                                  print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
                                  let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)}  } task.resume()  }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellGecmis", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewTaxCell

        if(collectionView == self.collectionView2) {
            let article = itemsSon[indexPath.row]

            cell?.ustIsımLabel.text = article.baslik
            cell?.ustPriceLabel.text = article.fiyat
            cell?.ustSureLabel.text = article.aciklama

           }
}
    }
```

Comment: Please format the code. It's rather unreadable. And **where** does the error occur?

Comment: I updated topics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error (apart from the confusion `detayTaxSonItem` vs `detayTaxItemSON`) is pretty clear:

Assigning a default value to a `let` property makes it immutable and no implicit memberwise initializer is provided. So only `init()` is available which takes no arguments

---

```
let aciklama: Array = [""]
```

is bad practice anyway. You are declaring a string array with one (empty) item which is likely not intended.

To get constants but also the memberwise initializer declare your struct as follows (and name structs and classes always with starting uppercase letter)

```
struct DetayTaxItemSON {
    let aciklama : [String]
    let baslik : [String]
    let fiyat : [String]
    let adet : [String]
    let tarih : [String]
}
```

Comment: For example, there are two variables assigned to date data. While it needs to print separately, "2020-02-25 22:09, 2020-04-25 22:09" prints as a single item without the comma in between as above. I want to assign more than one data

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question. Please ask a new one.